# d3 doesn't plot tree when there are exclusively single children?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It seems (please point out if I'm making a mistake) that if you try and plot a tree with a single line (i.e no bifurcation in children, each child only has a single child.) like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mhauserr/5995868) the d3 tree layout seems to fail to plot it.

on the other hand ensuring at least one splitting like [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mhauserr/5995892) it plots fine (I have also done a test for having a both a single leaf node and double leaf node in the same tree and this works fine as expected).

my question is to double check if this is a bug in d3 or in what I'm doing. if you click through to the examples I've given you can see the index.html's are the same (and taken exactly from mike bostacks example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550)) and the only difference is in the single extra json line.

I realise that there should be no cause to plot a single line using a tree grid but this is dynamically generated so I need to know if I should manually exclude these cases and write a message to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d3 tree itself doesn't care about nesting levels and children (or no children). I've tried your data in a generic tree example and it works fine.

The problem is the custom `.separation` function in the original example does not handle it well. If you look in the web console you'll see errors like this: `Unexpected value rotate(NaN)translate(120) parsing transform attribute.`

Try changing this line:

```
.separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });
```

to something like this (haven't evaluated closely what the original is actually trying to do):

```
  .separation(function(a, b) { 
    if (a.depth == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
    }
  });
```